# Create Client programmatically in Keycloak

Tags: java, keycloak, keycloak-services

How do I create clients programmatically in keycloak using java application?

Answer (score 9):

One way to do it is via the api :

- Get token for an account with the rights to add client to the realm

  ```
    POST https://<keycloak-url>/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token
    Host: <keycloak-url>
    Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
    Cache-Control: no-cache

    client_id=admin-cli&grant_type=password&username=<user>&password=<password>
  ```
- Add a new client (the request body comes from an export of an existing client)

  ```
    POST https://keycloak-url/auth/admin/realms/<realm-name>/clients
    Host: <keycloak-url>
    Content-Type: application/json
    Cache-Control: no-cache
    Authorization: Bearer <token>

    {
         "clientId": "test-add",
         "[...]"
     }
  ```

The response status should be a `201` with an header location to the new client.

Documentation can be found here : https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/14.0/rest-api/index.html#_clients_resource

Comment: If anyone is looking for the latest link it can be found here : [https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/14.0/rest-api/index.html#_clients_resource](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/14.0/rest-api/index.html#_clients_resource)

Comment: @sandy.sk thank you, I will update the answer

Answer (score 2):

I did it like this,

```
public boolean createClient(String clientId, String realmName) throws IOException {
    try {
        Keycloak keycloakInstanceDefault = KeycloakInstance.getInstance();
        RealmResource createdRealmResource = keycloakInstanceDefault.realms().realm(realmName);
        ClientRepresentation clientRepresentation = new ClientRepresentation();
        clientRepresentation.setClientId(clientId);
        clientRepresentation.setProtocol("openid-connect");
        clientRepresentation.setSecret(clientId);
        createdRealmResource.clients().create(clientRepresentation);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

KeycloakInstance.getInstance(); returns Keycloak Object.

Answer (score 2):

#### Using curl

```
#get token
RESULT=`curl --data "username=<your_admin_user>&password=<your_passwod>&grant_type=password&client_id=admin-cli" http://localhost:8090/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token`
TOKEN=`echo $RESULT | sed 's/.*access_token":"//g' | sed 's/".*//g'`
#create user
curl -X POST -d '{ "clientId": "myclient" }' -H "Content-Type:application/json" -H "Authorization: bearer ${TOKEN}" http://localhost:8090/auth/realms/master/clients-registrations/default
```

Comment: TOKEN=$(curl -s -d 'username=admin&password=admin&grant_type=password&client_id=admin-cli' 'http://localhost:8090/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token' | jq '.token_type + " " + .access_token')

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this via the **client-credentials** grant type. For this, your client needs to be configured as follows:

- Turn **ON** the **Service Accounts Enabled** option under the **Settings** tab of your client.
- Assign necessary **realm-management** client roles to your client. For this, switch to **Service Admin Roles** tab, select **realm-management** from the dropdown, and assign **manage-clients** role under **Client Roles**.

Then, you should be able to use this client to create another client in the same realm. Please refer to the below sample curls.

Retrieve a token:

```
curl --location '<Keycloak URL>/auth/realms/<realm>/protocol/openid-connect/token' \
        --header 'Accept: application/json' \
        --header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
        --header 'Authorization: Basic <Base64 encode(client ID:client secret)>' \
        --data 'grant_type=client_credentials&scope=openid'
```

Create the client:

```
    curl --location '<Keycloak URL>/auth/admin/realms/<realm>/clients' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer <token retrieved above>' \
--header 'Accept: application/json' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data '{<export of your existing client>}'
```